# How do I style the gold-email-input Polymer element?

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I am trying to change the label color of the `<gold-email-input>` element.

I have tried the following:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  gold-email-input {
    --paper-input-container-color: white!important;
    --paper-input-container-focus-color: white!important;
    --paper-input-container-invalid-color: white!important;
    --paper-input-container-input-color: white!important;
  }
</style>
```

But it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: currently i am using this .paper-input-white * {
        color: white!important;
    }

Comment: Your example works for me ie. all the texts are white. Just your <gold-email-input> -tag and your stylings, no modification

Comment: Have you included the custom style in the element where gole-email is used? You need to provide more details on your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.white-color * {
    color: white!important;
}
```

this will only opt when gold-email-input is in body

```
  gold-email-input {
    --paper-input-container-color: white!important;
    --paper-input-container-focus-color: white!important;
    --paper-input-container-invalid-color: white!important;
    --paper-input-container-input-color: white!important;
  }
```

above will work only if the gold-email-element inside dom-module